# Given two well-orders $\langle A,R \rangle$ and $\langle B,S \rangle$, one of the following holds.

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

Let $\langle A,R \rangle$ and $\langle B,S \rangle$ be two well-orders, and let $\text{pred}(A,x,R) := \{y \in A \;|\; yRx\}$ and similarly for $\text{pred}(B,z,S)$.

It is claimed that one of the following must hold:

$1$. $\langle A,R \rangle \cong \langle B,S \rangle$.

$2$. $\exists y \in B\left(\langle A,R \rangle \cong \langle \text{pred}(B,y,S),S\rangle\right)$.

$3$. $\exists x \in A\left(\langle \text{pred}(A,x,R), R \rangle \cong \langle B,S \rangle \right)$.

The proof of this seems like a sketch, giving us $f := \{\langle v,w \rangle\;:\: v \in A \land w \in B \land \text{pred}(A,v,R), R \rangle \cong \langle \text{pred}(B,w,S),S\rangle\}$

and it is claimed that it can not be the case that both initial segments are proper, which I interpret as $\neg (\text{pred}(A,v,R) \subsetneqq A \land \text{pred}(B,w,S) \subsetneqq B)$.

First: Is my understanding of what is claimed correct?

Second: Given that my understanding of what is claimed is correct, I fail to see why this can't be the case. I don't know exactly how to proceed. Any illumination on how to think would be well appreciated.

This question is motivated by the proof of lemma $6.3$, chapter $1$, in Kunen's "Introduction to independence proof's".

Comment: Your formal rendering of the natural language claim "both initial segments cannot be proper" is indeed correct. The notation $\mathrm{pred}$ is hideous -- by the way -- the natural way of referring to the interval of all $y$'s strictly below a given $x$ with respect to order $R$ being $(\leftarrow, x)_{R}$. The meaning of this fundamental result -- as I believe you already understand -- is that given any two well-ordered sets one will necessarily be isomorphic to an initial segment of the other. *(to be continued)*

Comment: *(cont.)* In general it can and will very well happen that two proper initial segments of two given well-ordered sets be isomorphic: this is the case for instance with the *empty* proper segment, proper in any *nonempty* ordered set. In order to give a proof for the fundamental theorem of dichotomy between well-ordered sets I would suggest the following: 1) a given initial segment of $A$ can be isomorphic to at most one initial segment of $B$ via at most one isomorphism; 2) considering the well-ordered (via inclusion) set $\mathscr{S}$ of initial segments of $A$ isomorphic *(to be cont.)*

Comment: *(cont.)* isomorphic to some initial segment of $B$, $\mathscr{S}$ can be shown to have a maximum, i.e. there is *a largest* initial segment $A'$ of $A$ isomorphic to some initial segment of $B$; 3) if this largest initial segment of $A$ is actually $A$ itself, the proof is concluded; if not, the unique initial segment of $B$ to which $A'$ is isomorphic must be $B$ itself for otherwise the maximality of $A'$ would be breached (specifically, if $A'=(\leftarrow, a)_{R}$ and $B'=(\leftarrow, b)_{R}$ were isomorphic so would also $(\leftarrow, a]_{R}$ and $(\leftarrow, b]_{R}$ be...)

Comment: Oh, I found this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Well-Ordering

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is

1. $f$ is a function on its domain.  In other words, for all $v\in A$, there is *at most* one $w\in B$ such that $\langle v,w\rangle\in f$.  Use lemma 6.1 for this.
2. $f$ is order-preserving- if $v_1<_Rv_2$ in $A$, $v_1,v_2\in\text{dom}(f)$ then $f(v_1)<_S f(v_2)$ in $B$.
3. $\text{dom}(f)$ is an initial segment of $\langle A,R\rangle$ and $\text{ran}(f)$ is an initial segment of $\langle B,S\rangle$.
4. $\text{dom}(f)$ and $\text{ran}(f)$ cannot both be proper initial segments (of $A, B$ respectively) because then you could extend $f$ by one more mapping so $f$ is not maximal.

Comment: Hm, I am having a hard time proving $2$.

Comment: @Ben123 To look at the above indications in a somewhat different light, the binary relation $F$ as defined in your proof outline is *functional*: if $(x, y), (x, z) \in F$ with, say, $y \leqslant_S z$ then $(\leftarrow, y)_S$ and $(\leftarrow, z)_S$ are both isomorphic to $(\leftarrow, x)_R$ hence isomorphic to each other. However, $(\leftarrow, y)_S$ is an initial segment of $(\leftarrow, z)$ and I trust your course material thus far has familiarised you with the fundamental fact that a well ordered set is never isomorphic to a *proper* initial segment. *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thanks for your input. I believe I understood the proof as outlined on proofwiki, atleast in broad strokes. I just started with this course so I am still getting used to the notation. Right now I am trying to understand ordinal-addition, but that is unrelated to this =)

Comment: @Ben123 *(cont.1)* Hence, with necessity $y=z$. One goes on to notice that the *domain* of relation $F$ is an initial segment of $A$: if $x, s \in A$ are such that $(x, y) \in F$ for a certain $y$ and $s<_R x$, whatever (unique) order isomorphism exists between $(\leftarrow, x)_R$ and $(\leftarrow, y)_S$ will isomorphically map the *proper* initial segment $(\leftarrow, s)_R$ of $(\leftarrow, x)_R$ onto a *proper* initial segment of $(\leftarrow, y)_S$, which by necessity is of the form $(\leftarrow, t)_S$ with $t<_S y$. Thus $(s, t) \in F$ and $s$ also belongs to the domain of $F$.

Comment: @Ben123 *(cont.2)* A reasoning similar to that of *(cont.1)* above also tells us that the *range* of $F$ is an initial segment of $B$; if we denote the domain (range) of $F$ by $A'$ ($B'$) we can furthermore infer from the same reasoning that the function $f=(A', F, B')$ is *strictly increasing*: indeed, in the above notations we have $t=f(s)<_S y=f(x)$, under the hypothesis that $s<_R x$. Thus, as it is a strictly increasing surjection defined on a totally ordered set, $f$ is seen to actually be an order isomorphism.

Comment: @Ben123 *(cont.3)* At this point, to reach the desired conclusion it suffices to establish that at least one of $A', B'$ is improper. Proceeding by *reductio ad absurdum* we claim they both were *proper* initial segments, which would mean $A'=(\leftarrow, a)_R, B'=(\leftarrow, b)_S$ for a certain pair $a \in A, b \in B$. However, if this were the case we would have $(a, b) \in F$ (recall that $f$ is an isomorphism!) and hence $a \in A'$, which is absurd!